# The Image tag with `crossOrigin="Anonymous"` can't load success from S3

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3

In javascript

`const image = new Image()
image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'
image.src = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/ch-static-beta/avatar/user/1a8fdd22d5ec11e784da0e28350150f71512059569.png'`

will get an error of 
[image]

And the http header is 
[image]

But when I use the `curl` and with this request header, the response will success. like this.[image]

Comment: Interesting - I don't have a problem with that image at all ... loads successfully - which browser are you using?

Comment: AHA, with this image? I load this image in chrome console, the Error emit as well.@JaromandaX

Comment: Odd - works fine in **every browser I've tried** - Firefox, IE, Edge and surprisingly even Chrome

Comment: Amazing! I tried this in windows OS, this image will load successfully. And in mac OS will fail.@JaromandaX

Comment: Amazing! I cleaned the cached image, and with those code in chrome console, the Image will load successfully. It's a BUG?@Kaiido

Comment: Cache works on mysterious ways. Did you add the cors stuff on the server after an initial failure? The perils of development

Comment: @JaromandaX, The code work fine in last long time. This error emit in those days. And we are not change the server.

Comment: I doubt it, but as you say

Comment: Also "I doubt it"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's a caching issue, [<s>and a chrome bug</s>](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718352&can=1&q=cache%20crossOrigin&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)*:

<sub>*Closed as WONT-FIX, chrome devs said it isn't a bug per se, it's a misconfiguration of the server which should send the allow origin headers to any requests... A related [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409090), also closed as WONT-FIX.</sub>

You probably already had made a request to this image without requesting for the CORS headers.

When you perform the second request, the browser will <s>wrongly</s> reuse the cached response.

```js
var rand = '?'+Math.random();
var no_cors = new Image();
no_cors.onload = loadCORS;
no_cors.src = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/ch-static-beta/avatar/user/1a8fdd22d5ec11e784da0e28350150f71512059569.png' + rand;


function loadCORS(){
  var with_cors = new Image();
  with_cors.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  with_cors.src = no_cors.src;
  with_cors.onload = function(){console.log('loaded');};
  with_cors.onerror = function(){console.error('failed');};
}
```

So for a fix: [...] <s>Configure your S3 so that it always sends the cross-origin headers.</s>*
For a workaround, always load the crossOrigin version.
For a temp fix, disable caching.

*It seems it's not possible to setup S3 to do so, see [this excellent answer](https://serverfault.com/a/856948/153161) by [Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot), which also provides other server-side workarounds.

Comment: As you say, I added a timestamp to the url fixed this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Kalido your diagnosis concurs with mine, at https://serverfault.com/a/856948/153161.  This is an issue with S3... it is not currently possible to directly configure it to always return CORS headers, or even `Vary: Origin` for a non-CORS request.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot great answer, I am hesitating to create an account just to upvote it, learned a lot since I'm not in the server-side of things.

Answer (score 0):

I have work on this bug almost 2 years. I thing the problems is related in Amazon servers. I try crossOrigin - no effect. I try to add timestapm query url param - no effect. disable cache or enable cache - no effect. Sometime works, other - no.

Try with chrome edge - not shown image. Try with chrome - image are shown.

And Yes, each of these "workarounds" seems to work for some users. Be sure!!! One day image again will not shown even you did not change/update any of your code/projects.

If you check "disable cache" from inspect. Then after some hours/days/restart everything may work fine.  But this is not a fix!!!

the only partial fix is this bad code

```
image.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
   image.src = "images/notfound.jpg";
    
};
```

Comment: The answer I accepted works for me.  In fact, the cause of this issue is before we edit the image, we have loaded the image using `<img src="......" />`. this loading does not have `crossOrigin`. after that, we reload the image with `crossOrigin`, the browser use cache. so when you edit the image it will CORS.