# Typescript - Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, canvas

I am building an Ionic App and I am getting this error when I try to convert to base64 an image from an URL.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

My code is the following:

```
public getBase64Image(imgUrl: string): Promise<string> {
    if (!imgUrl.includes("http")) {
      return;
    }

    return new Promise<string>(resolve => {
      let img = new Image();

      img.src = imgUrl;
      img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
      img.onload = (() => {
        let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        resolve(dataURL);
      });
    });
  }
```

I've read other questions where setting `anonymous` in `crossOrigin` was the solution, but I already have it.

Hope you can help me, thanks.

**EDIT 1**

As a note, I don't get this the first time that I convert an image to base64 but I get it in the following times I try to edit an image.

Comment: Tou may like to read this: [Tainted canvases may not be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported)

Comment: I tried that also but not working @enxaneta . I did an edit on the first post

Comment: try this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/

Comment: `ctx.drawImage` is an asynchronus function. Maybe you try to convert it to base64  while its drawing on the canvas. Maybe thats why a conflict happen. You need to be sure, that the context is rendered done.

Comment: @Jonathan here it says it's void, doesn't return a promise https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: that doesn't work @Najamussaqib , it returns an empty string

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported ?

Comment: May this could help you too: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/182/the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data-and-tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported

Comment: @Jonathan Yes but I have no access over the server side

Comment: When you say *"but I get it in the following times I try to edit an image"*, you mean you already did load it without the crossOrigin attribute? Then it's a cache issue (and while Chrome guys don not agree, a Chrome bug...). This could happen because your server don't send the proper Allow-Origin:vary headers when no crossOrigin is set, and that the browser will then keep using this resource from cache even when the attribute is set. The solution is to always require your images with the crossOrigin attribute, ir to set up your server correctly (but AWS S3 for one can't be set up in this way)

Comment: @Kaiido I always require it (I think) with the code above. What I don't understand is what you say, why I can do it once without any error but then on the next times I try to download it I get the error. It's an Ionic App, idk how much it's related to Chrome. I've solved it with a different approach on my answer but I'd like to know why this happens.

Comment: That may not be what I understood then. You mean that you can load 'img1.jpg', and export it to a dataURL once, but when you try to load again that same 'img1.jpg' it will throw? I actually can't see a reason... [Here is what I thought you were facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503171/the-image-tag-with-crossorigin-anonymous-cant-load-success-from-s3/49503414#49503414) (don't hesitate to read the linked answer @serverfault, it's worth it). Oh and if in your answer you are talking about [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42916772), then don't be afraid of dropping an upvote ;-)

Comment: Yes, thats what's happening, I get the error if I try to download the same image again. Sadl I don't have control over the server side. This post is what I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64 sry :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the approach in the first post, I've switched to downloading the image using Angular's HttpClient and then getting its base64.

Code:

```
public getBase64Image(imgUrl: string): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.http.get(imgUrl, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(data => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(data);
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          observer.next(reader.result.toString().replace(":application/octet-stream;", ":image/png;"));
          observer.complete();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```