# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Looks like the issue is related mostly to my aws s3 bucket CORS config

I added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

to my bucket CORS config, but this didn't help either.  For some reason I am able to add the photos to the canvas, (depending on the code) but not able to save the canvas with the image from AWS

---

I have a fabric.js canvas that is being tainted on images from amazon s3.  I am unsure on exactly what is going on.

**When I try to save the canvas by clicking save:**

Chrome Error on console: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

FireFox Error on console: Operation is insecure

https://jsfiddle.net/je3mL5go/1/

In the jsfiddle, it works when the added line `}, {crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'});` is present.

**In production on Heroku with s3 Images:**

In FireFox, I can select an image from the select menu and have it add to the canvas.  I'll get the error as mentioned but if I repeatedly click the "Save" button, after enough clicks (usually 5-30), it will allow me to save the canvas as a png.

In Chrome, this "hack" doesn't seem to work at all.

Is there an explanation behind this?

It also seems that because I am hosting the images in AWS S3, this effects it as well.  But even with this, the above example (repeat clicking in FireFox) still works.

Attempts:

With:

```
function updateTshirtImage(imageURL){
  fabric.Image.fromURL(imageURL, function(img) {
    img.scaleToHeight(300);
    img.scaleToWidth(300);
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    canvas.centerObject(img);
    canvas.add(img);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
};
```

I am able to upload the image but when i click save:

I get the same errors as above.

When i use:

```
function updateTshirtImage(imageURL){
  fabric.Image.fromURL(imageURL, function(img) {
     img.scaleToHeight(300);
     img.scaleToWidth(300);
     canvas.centerObject(img);
     canvas.add(img);
     canvas.renderAll();
  }, {crossOrigin: 'anonymous'});
};
```

Error on upload by select image

`No 'Access-Control-Origin-Header' is present...`

Attempt:

```
function updateTshirtImage(imageURL){
   var rand = '?'+Math.random();
   var no_cors = new Image();
   no_cors.onload = loadCORS;
   no_cors.src = imageURL + rand;

   function loadCORS(){
     var with_cors = new Image();
     with_cors.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
     with_cors.src = no_cors.src;
     with_cors.onload = function(){console.log('loaded');};
     with_cors.onerror = function(){console.error('failed');};
     fabric.Image.fromURL(with_cors.src, function(img) {
     img.scaleToHeight(300);
     img.scaleToWidth(300);
     canvas.centerObject(img);
     canvas.add(img);
     canvas.renderAll();
   }, {crossOrigin: 'anonymous'});
  }
};

var images = <%= images_2.to_h.to_json.html_safe %>
document.getElementById("tshirt-design").addEventListener("change", function(){
    updateTshirtImage(images[this.value]);
}, false);
```

error:

Chrome: 404 error

Firefox: No error, not working.

Is the issue here is that I'm somehow changing the url for aws s3 before asking for it from aws?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tainted canvases may not be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported)

Comment: What if you clear all cache and start again with Chrome, with all your assets loaded with the crossOrigin flag? See this related Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503171/the-image-tag-with-crossorigin-anonymous-cant-load-success-from-s3/49503414#49503414

Comment: thanks I think this is the best solution yet for it all.  my attempts are added but I cannot still get it to work

Comment: @Phil I attemped the crossOrigin in the javascript but it didn't help in my case.  I can only assume there is some order in my code i am missing out on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adding of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Actually did the trick.  Looks like I just needed to wait.  The next day I tested and it worked!

To clarify, the above header code is probably overkill but this is where I am currently at.  I will be testing and "debugging" and removing some Allowed Methods and see which and which are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still encountering the same issue even after applying the server cross-origin settings, it probably a browser caching issue.
So you need to make sure to disable the caching and test again, you can do that from the browser dev-tools -> network tab -> click on disable cash option -> try again:
[Chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erweS.png)