# React js: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource while using htmlToImage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use htmlToImage method but is showing the error "Access to fetch at " / aws image url / " from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The image url which I am using in img tag is coming from aws s3 bucket. And on AWS s3 we have already configured CORS

AllowedOrigins as "*".
AllowedHeaders as "*".

This is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as htmlToImage from "html-to-image";

export default class DownloadableImage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
   
    }
  }
 handleDownloadImage = ()=>{
  const post = document.getElementById("generateImage");
    htmlToImage
      .toJpeg(post, {
        style: {
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
        },
        quality: 0.95,
      })
      .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = "download.jpeg";
        link.href = dataUrl;
        link.click();
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error, "error"));
}
  render() {
    return (  
        <div id="generateImage">
            <img class="img-style" src="imgUrl" alt="download_image"> 
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleDownloadImage}>Download</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Community, Please help me out.

Comment: Could you tell me where can i insert in my code, which is you provided code.?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add cors configuration to your bucket properties.

Refer to this thread for more details: [S3 - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533888/s3-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 0):

there is a checklist for you.

1、If you want to edit an image, you should add the `crossOrigin` attribute to the `img` node.

2、Note, In [My case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503171/the-image-tag-with-crossorigin-anonymous-cant-load-success-from-s3). I got the cached image, and the image request doesn't send the `cross origin` header. So it will get an error.